# Is there a way to specify a default validation rule in FluentValidation?

Tags: fluentvalidation

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public string Baz { get; set; }
}
```

and validation rules like this:

```
RuleFor(c => c.Foo).NotEmpty();
RuleFor(c => c.Bar).NotNull();  // Bar is allowed to be empty string
RuleFor(c => c.Baz).NotEmpty();
```

Is there a way to express a default rule that is used to validate any properties that don't have a specific rule specified?  Something like this that should give the same validation result as above?

```
RuleFor(c => c.Bar).NotNull();
DefaultRule().NotEmpty();
```

Answer (score 1):

SO, I asked Jeremy Skinner (creator of FluentValidation) the same question and very quickly received the following answer.

---

No that's not possible out of the box I'm afraid. The idea behind FluentValidation is to provide a way to explicitly define strongly-typed rules against specific properties. This kind of defeats the purpose of that, so isn't something I'd be keen on including.
That being said, if you really want this functionality you may be able to build it as an extension. You'd have to do the following:

1. Use reflection to find all properties on the target object
2. Check if there are already rules defined in the validator for that property
3. For properties that don't have rules, construct a PropertyRule instance
4. For each rule, apply the validators you want in the default

Here's a quick example (untested). You'd need to introduce caching to prevent the reflection on every instantiation of the validator:

```
public static class DefaultRuleExtension 
{
    public static void DefaultRule<T>(this AbstractValidator<T> validator, Action<IRuleBuilder<T, object>> defaultRuleBuilder) 
    {
        var existingPropertiesWithRules = validator.OfType<PropertyRule>().Select(x => x.PropertyName).ToList();

        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(x => !existingPropertiesWithRules.Contains(x.Name));

        //TODO: Make sure you cache the properties and the expression tree so the reflection isn't performed on every instantiation.
        foreach (var property in properties) 
        {
            var expression = BuildGetterExpression<T>(property);
            var rule = PropertyRule.Create(expression);

            validator.AddRule(rule);
            var ruleBuilder = new RuleBuilder<T, object>(rule, validator);
            defaultRuleBuilder(ruleBuilder);
        }
    }

    private static Expression<Func<T, object>> BuildGetterExpression<T>(PropertyInfo prop) 
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        Expression expression = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, prop.Name);

        if (prop.PropertyType.IsValueType)
            expression = Expression.Convert(expression, typeof(object));

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(expression, param);
    }
}
```

Usable like this:

```
public class DemoValidator : AbstractValidator<Person> {
    public DemoValidator() {
        this.DefaultRule(r => {
            r.NotEmpty();
        });
    }
}
```